# Finding the percentages of missing information in each column in parallel using bigmemory and parallel packages in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply, jobs, na

Here's what I want to do:

```
> library(parallel)
> library(bigmemory)
> big.mat=read.big.matrix("cp2006.csv",header=T)
Warning messages:
1: In na.omit(as.integer(firstLineVals)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In na.omit(as.double(firstLineVals)) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In read.big.matrix("cp2006.csv", header = T) :
  Because type was not specified, we chose double based on the first line of data.
> jobs <- lapply(1:10, function(x) mcparallel(colMeans(is.na(big.mat))*100, name = big.mat))
Error in as.character.default(name) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
> res  <- mccollect(jobs)
```

However the problem is that `is.na` is not apparently applicable to `big.matrix` objects. I did a search on web and found `mwhich` which is the parallel version of `which` in `bigmemory` but unfortunately couldn't find a good tutorial on it to find the missing (`NA`) values in the column. So I am not sure what function I should feed to my `mcparallel` to make it work with `big.matrix` objects. 
In addition:

```
> col.NA.mean<-colMeans(is.na(big.mat))*100
Error in colMeans(is.na(big.mat)) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(big.mat) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
```

Comment: Not sure if you've seen [this R-bloggers post about bigmemory](http://www.r-bloggers.com/michael-kane-on-bigmemory/), but there is mention of the airline data set and links that may be useful.

Comment: Use `biganalytics::apply(yourBigMatrix, ...)` for faster operations on either row or columns. Note there is also `biganalytics::colmean(yourBigMatrix, ...)` and other similar functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. When we call big.mat we should use `[,]` so here's the partial answer.

```
> colMeans(is.na(big.mat[,]))
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
       0.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
       0.02102102        0.00000000        0.02402402        0.00000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       1.00000000        0.00000000        0.97997998        0.02402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
       0.00000000        0.02402402        0.02402402        0.02102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       1.00000000        1.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
       0.00000000        0.00000000        1.00000000        0.00000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
       0.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000        0.00000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
       0.00000000
```

Here's the answer:

```
library(parallel)
library(bigmemory)
big.mat=read.big.matrix("cp2006.csv",header=T)
Warning messages:
1: In na.omit(as.integer(firstLineVals)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In na.omit(as.double(firstLineVals)) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In read.big.matrix("cp2006.csv", header = T) :
Because type was not specified, we chose double based on the first line of data.
jobs <- lapply(1:10, function(x) mcparallel(colMeans(is.na(big.mat[,]))*100, name = big.mat))
Error in as.character.default(name) : 
no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
jobs <- lapply(1:10, function(x) mcparallel(colMeans(is.na(big.mat[,]))*100, name = big.mat[,]))
res  <- mccollect(jobs)
> res
$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

$`2006`
             Year             Month        DayofMonth         DayOfWeek 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          DepTime        CRSDepTime           ArrTime        CRSArrTime 
         2.102102          0.000000          2.402402          0.000000 
    UniqueCarrier         FlightNum           TailNum ActualElapsedTime 
       100.000000          0.000000         97.997998          2.402402 
   CRSElapsedTime           AirTime          ArrDelay          DepDelay 
         0.000000          2.402402          2.402402          2.102102 
           Origin              Dest          Distance            TaxiIn 
       100.000000        100.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
          TaxiOut         Cancelled  CancellationCode          Diverted 
         0.000000          0.000000        100.000000          0.000000 
     CarrierDelay      WeatherDelay          NASDelay     SecurityDelay 
         0.000000          0.000000          0.000000          0.000000 
LateAircraftDelay 
         0.000000 

>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a part answer. `is.na` appears to work fine.

```
library(bigmemory)
```

Some data, from examples in `?big.matrix`

```
x <- big.matrix(10, 2, type='integer', init=-5)
options(bigmemory.allow.dimnames=TRUE)
colnames(x) <- c("alpha", "beta")
is.big.matrix(x)
dim(x)
colnames(x)
rownames(x)
```

Set some to missing

```
x[1,] <- NA
x[,]
#      alpha beta
# [1,]    NA   NA
# [2,]    -5   -5
# ...

 is.na(x[,] )
 #       alpha  beta
 # [1,]  TRUE  TRUE
 # [2,] FALSE FALSE
 # ...

 y <- as.big.matrix(is.na(x[,]))
# Warning message:
# In as.big.matrix(is.na(x[, ])) : Casting to numeric type

is.big.matrix(y)
# [1] TRUE

 y[,]
#      alpha beta
# [1,]     1    1
# [2,]     0    0
# [3,]     0    0
# [4,]     0    0
# [5,]     0    0
# [6,]     0    0
# [7,]     0    0
# [8,]     0    0
# [9,]     0    0
#[10,]     0    0

 colMeans(y[,])
# alpha  beta 
#  0.1   0.1
```

So i think you need to add the `[,]` after `big.mat`.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine when I use it with the attach.big.matrix like `is.na(x[,] )` however when I want to feed it to lapply using `colmean` from `biganalytics` or `colMeans` it doesn't work.

Comment: It's really weird that we have to do all these middle steps to get the result. However I appreciate your idea of making it work.

Comment: @MonaJalal; difficult to say; `lapply(1:2, function(i) colMeans(is.na(x[,])))` appears to work. Good luck

Comment: Can you please take a look at my answer? Why does `mccollect` returns too many result? I expected it to return something similar to just using `colMeans`.

Comment: Also can you please verify if my answer makes sense?

Comment: @MonaJalal;  I am not familiar with the `parallel` package. But your `lapply` makes 10 calls the same - hence the 10 outputs that are the same. Of course i dont know if this is needed for `mcparallel`. Check my small `lapply` example in the comment above - i get a list of 2 outputs as that is what was passed in the `lapply`.

Comment: I think there should be a relation to the number of cores in the cluster we want to distribute the jobs in between and that 1:10. I kind of wanted to use 10 cores but apparently I was wrong.